# Limit access to a file by program in Unix/Linux

Tags: permissions

Is it possible to limit access to a file by a program.

The problem I have is that users run a program under their UID and it accesses a file. I want that file not to be accessible to them through file-system.

> The program is java -jar myProgram.jar filePathAsParameter

Thank you

Comment: the file should be owned by ur user , and must have permissions r,w,x only by ur user!     
`chown user:group file ; chmod 700 file`  ( sudo chown $USER:$USER /path/to/file ; sudo chmod 700 /path/to/file; )

Comment: @younes that way the users won't be able to access the file through the java program that they run.

Comment: @Alex, do your users have to run the program under their own UID? Or can they run it as someone else. If so then you can change the permissions on your file like younes suggests and then use `setuid` on the java file to run the program as another user who has access to the file.

Comment: They have to use their own UID

Comment: Then you might use a group and `setgid` for that control.  This is how, for example, games are usually configured to protect access to the top scores file.

Comment: @MAP , are you suggesting to setgit to the jar or the file (the one I want to restrict permission)?

Comment: You need whatever is the executable to be `setgid` (there's no git involved :-).  Depending on details which I don't know that may require a shim.  `setgid` is just like `setuid` except it uses group permissions.  I swear I just wrote this answer somewhere yesterday.

Comment: OK, I found that other [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295043/give-user2-read-only-permission-to-user1s-subdirectory/295051).  It's not exactly tailored to your situation, but might help.

Comment: @MAP Not working... The program which actually is executed is java

Comment: You need a shim in that case.  I'm too busy to write this answer at this moment, I'll try and write this up as a full answer tomorrow.